# FFmpeg uses too much memory when repeating split, select, overlay

Tags: performance, video, ffmpeg, scripting, video-processing

I'm running

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex_script script.txt output.mp4
```

with the following minimal example script:

```
split[tmp],
select='between(t,1,2)',
select='between(n,0,1)',
[tmp]overlay=enable='between(t,1,2)':eof_action=repeat,
split[tmp],
select='between(t,3,4)',
select='between(n,0,1)',
[tmp]overlay=enable='between(t,3,4)':eof_action=repeat
```

What I want to do is to take 1 frame at a certain position and repeat it for a certain duration, basically "pausing" the video, while overwriting to keep the same output length. In the example, I'm doing this twice: I'm using `split[tmp]` to get a second input stream to work on, select the time at position 00:01 with `select='between(t,1,2)'`, select the first frame from that position with `select='between(n,0,1)'` and finally overlay that frame over the input. This repeats for a second time at position 00:03. I have tested this and it does exactly what I'm looking for.

However, in my real script, I'm repeating this about 1000 times for different positions in the stream (and for shorter durations than 1 second) which results in running out of memory. What am I doing wrong? What can I do to optimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters in ffmpeg operate fundamentally on frames and not a stream. So each select filter will evaluate each frame, even though you know that only a few frames at the start will qualify for selection. Doing that 1000 times is not resource-cheap.

For your use case, you don't need most of this. Only a single select filter will do.

`select='if(eq(n,0),1,not((between(t,1.0,1.999)+between(t,3.0,3.999)+between(t,5.0,5.999))*eq(floor(t),floor(prev_selected_t))))'`

This will keep all frames outside of the ranges [1-1.999], [3-3.999] and [5-5.999] and the first frames inside those ranges. If your output format requires constant frame-rate, ffmpeg will duplicate frames to plug timestamp gaps.